# Trying to run hadoop on windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, protocol-buffers

I am trying to run hadoop in my machine (Windows x64), but I get this error when building the sources:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.3.0:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionExcepti
on: 'protoc --version' did not return a version -> [Help 1]
```

As suggested in the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) and explained in the BUILDING.txt, I have in my PATH vble the protoc path and from my Windows SDK I can call 'protoc --version' with no problem:

```
C:\Users\hernanbl\Downloads\hadoop-2.3.0-src\hadoop-common-project>protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

Besides, the version is the same as used in hadoop 2.3.0 (the version I am trying to build). As defined in the documentation, I made further changes, such as declaring a Platform vble and so on.

I already googled the question and I found that I might not be the only one having this issue, but the answers don´t give me the clue to fix this...

Some ideas?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by setting the environment variable pointing to the executable:

```
set HADOOP_PROTOC_PATH=C:\Path\To\protoc\protoc.exe
```

Comment: protoc.exe can be downloaded here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads at the time of this writing, you will need version 2.5 here:  http://protobuf.googlecode.com/files/protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip

Answer (score 1):

I got it.... still a solution I don´t like at all!  If someone found a better one, please let me know:

Modify the class ProtocMojo, hardcoding the absolute path to the protoc.exe:

```
protocCommand= "C:\\development\\tools\\protoc\\protobuf-2.5.0\\src\\protoc.exe";
```